# How to define rounded numberPicker?

Tags: android

I want to give the application user the ability to choose number between 1..200

I trying to find something like numberPicker but i want it to be in round and the user will be able to drag a kind of slider on this circle

And according this this slider - the choose number will be define.

I can't find anything like it - but i saw in a lot of application this controller.

any help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build it very simply, however there is a very [good library](https://github.com/neild001/SeekArc) out there.

**Sampl, how to use**

```
  <com.triggertrap.seekarc.SeekArc
        android:id="@+id/seekArc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="30dp"
        seekarc:rotation="180"
        seekarc:startAngle="30"
        seekarc:sweepAngle="300"
        seekarc:touchInside="true" />
```